# ¿Como usar un ChangeListener que se ejecute solo cuando los cambios se realizan desde la UI?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, spinner

Tengo un JSpinner al que le agregue un ChangeListener porque no se puede agregar un ActionListener. El problema es que necesito que el Listener se ejecute solo cuando los cambios los realiza el usuario desde la UI, y que **NO** se ejecute cuando el cambio se realice desde el código, por ejemplo con un `setValue()`.